# statsmodels autocorrelation doesn't use all values

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, statsmodels, autocorrelation

I have some values over time that i plot with the autocorrelation:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/wwwusage.csv', names=['value'], header=0)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
axes[0].plot(df.value); axes[0]
plot_acf(df.value, ax=axes[1])

plt.show()
```

Which return this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmRkZ.png), but should return this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFif0.png).

If i use the normal acf function without the plot, I get some more values in the [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhyAA.png) but still not all:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/wwwusage.csv', names=['value'], header=0)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
axes[0].plot(df.value)
axes[1].plot(acf(df.value))

plt.show()
```

Why is that? I use the same variable df.value in both plots.

Edit:

If i use pandas i get this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmNKT.png), that doesn't seem right. And I'd really like to use the first function I mentioned, since it's the best plot visualisation:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/wwwusage.csv', names=['value'], header=0)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
axes[0].plot(df.value)
df_value_acf = [df.value.autocorr(i) for i in range(1,len(df.value))]
axes[1].plot(df_value_acf)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If I run your code (in the first code box), I get the plot that you said it should be returned

Comment: try the `lags`  keyword in plot_acf. IIRC the default number of lags has changed recently

Comment: What was the default value for lags before? I tried to use len(df.value) but get the error "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (298,) (296,) (298,)"
But I'm able to use a value close to the length of my data, still not the entire graph, though. But thank you very much, seems to be the problem!